# How to iterate over a dictionary and find the max values python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like such:

```
aDict = {'a': [1,2,3],
         'b': [2,3,4],
         'c': [3,3,6], ...}
```

How would I create a list that stores the maximum values at each index, (0,1,2).
Thanks!

Comment: What would you expect the result to look like?

Comment: `[max(integers) for integers in aDict.values()] == [3, 4, 6]`

Comment: What is index `(0, 1, 2)`? Dictionaries don't have indices, only keys. In this case `{'a', 'b', 'c'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you want something like this:

```
>>> aDict = {'a':[1,2,3],'b':[2,3,4],'c':[3,3,6]}
>>> aList = [max(aDict[k]) for k in sorted(aDict.keys())]
>>> print aList
[3, 4, 6]
```

Or maybe this:

```
>>> aDict = {'a':[1,2,3],'b':[2,3,4],'c':[3,3,6]}
>>> aDict2 = dict((k, max(aDict[k])) for k in aDict.keys())
>>> print aDict2
{'a': 3, 'c': 6, 'b': 4}
```

Comment: In the latter you could use dictionary comprehension `{k: max(v) for k, v in aDict.iteritems()}` (replace `.iteritems` by `.items` if python 3).